# How to push content from server side to client side using SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have .NET solution where there are two applications.
solution
APP1
APP2

APP1 and APP2 has different APP Pools in IIS.

APP1 contains actual website where it has client ,server side code and signalR.
APP2 is a web API built in ASP.NET WEB API 2.2.

From APP2 I am Posting data to APP1 server side code and data is brocasted using SignalR among users by pushing content to client side code.

ideally ,WEB API's data should reach users instanstly however in my case APP1 needs refresh and it takes time.

below is the code in APP1 To push content to client side.

```
' SignalR Update all feeds in the list
Dim HubContext As IHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext(Of ActivityFeedHub)()
For Each ID As Integer In Feeds
    Dim result As Object = New With
                                    {
                                        .Success = True _
                                        , .Action = action.ToString() _
                                        , .ActivityFeedProfileID = feedID _
                                        , .UrlToReplace = DBSystem.Current.Subsites.HomeSite.URL
                                    }
    output.Remove("Result")
    output.Add(New JProperty("Result", JObject.FromObject(result)))

    ' Send the update to client
    HubContext.Clients.Group(ID).updateActivity(output.ToString())
```

I am new to SignalR any idea where i need to look up?

Any help or redirection will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't push data with SignalR from one app to clients connected with other app. Instead you should send data from one app to other app on server then each app will push same data with SignalR to its connected clients.